# Which convex $2n$-gons have symmetry group $D_n$ instead of $D_{2n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

The equilateral octagon $M$ in the first image has the same symmetry group as the small embedded square - namely the dihedral group $D_4$ - with $8$ elements and generators ${x,y}$ with $x^4 = e, y^2 = e $ and $yxy = x^{-1}$. I call M a 'woven' polygon because it can be generated from two squares with different radii. The second image shows the two squares.  Within some bounds on the radii, the resulting 'woven' polygon will be convex and equilateral and still retain the same symmetry group.

I have two questions.(1) Is there another generic name for this class of 'woven' polygons and (2) If the two embedded squares are constrained to have the same radii and rotated with respect to each other as in the second illustration below, the resulting polygon will be equiangular and the symmetry group is again $D_4$. Are these the only two ways to retain 'half' the symmetry of the regular case ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only the regular $n$-gon will have symmetry group of order $2n$.  So the "equilateral octagon" show is not regular, and there are equilateral octagons that would have less symmetry than a square (despite having equal length sides).

Comment: A regular n-gon has symmetry group D2n, but that is not the definition. It is not a case of "if and only if" . Look at the figure above and note that it has symmetry group D4 but it is certainly not a square. The equilateral issue is of no consequence.

Comment: Note that I said an $n$-gon has symmetry order $2n$ if and only if regular.  You may define it otherwise, but this is a two-sided implication.  Your example is an octagon with symmetry order 8 not 16, so while it has a dihedral symmetry like a square, this is not a counterexample to what I said.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that there are equilateral octagons with less symmetry than a square, but these woven polygons have the added structure of the two embedded squares, so being equilateral is only a small part of the structure.